# RPC port Map Failure Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, port, rpc

I m trying to run a Program using RPC of Adding two numbers on Mac OsX 10.6

Here is what i am doing:

> rpcgen -a -C add.x

It generates the files

> add.h,add_clnt.c,add_svc.c,add_server.c,add_client.c

Then Compile all the files using:

```
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -c -o add_clnt.o add_clnt.c
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -c -o add_client.o add_client.c
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -c -o add_xdr.o add_xdr.c
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -o add_client add_clnt.o add_client.o add_xdr.o 
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -c -o add_svc.o add_svc.c
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -c -o add_server.o add_server.c
gcc -g -DRPC_SVC_FG -o add_server add_svc.o add_server.o add_xdr.o
```

Run server in one remote console

```
./add_server
```

Run client in another console

```
./add_client localhost 23 35
```

23 and 35 are the number whose sum i want to be printed on the second console.
When i execute the following nothing appears on the server console.

If i try an ip address instead of localhost while running client
The error is:

```
RPC:Port mapper Failure
```

I am using MacOSX 10.6

Comment: For what it's worth, the only thing that's still using the RPC system you're looking at is NFS and supporting services. It's not a technology that anyone is using to build anything new, nor should it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

This was done on a Solaris system and you should see something similar on MacOSX.

After starting the add_server on the remote host, check that add_server has successfully registered with the remote portmapper. E.g.

```
remote> cat add.x
struct add_args {
    int a;
    int b;
};
typedef struct add_args add_args;
bool_t xdr_add_args();    


#define ADDPROG ((u_long)0x20000001)
#define ADDVERS ((u_long)1)
#define ADD ((u_long)1)   
extern int *add_1();  

remote> ./add_server &
remote> rpcinfo -t localhost 536870913
program 536870913 version 1 ready and waiting
```

536870913 is 0x20000001 in decimal.  See if the remote host can be reached from local host. If yes, then run the add_client.

```
local> ping remote
remote is alive
local> rpcinfo -t remote 536870913
program 536870913 version 1 ready and waiting
local> ./add_clnt remote 23 35
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error may appear when the rpcbind daemon (In charge on giving information about the port where the requested service is listening) does not give a response to the calling machine.

This can happen due to errors in NAT or firewalling. So, a first attempt to diagnose the problema, as with anything regarding networking, could involve verifying the connection is fine by making ping to every interface involved, from closest to furthest, making sure each jump works fine.